# Window location function for particular column click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `window.location` function in the table. In that table so many column are there and if I click any of column that `window.location` function is work. but I want to use `window .location` function of particular column. If I click on any column that `window.location` function should work.

Please give me any suggestion.

Comment: You need to a) provide any existing code of what you have tried and b) try to explain what you mean a little more clearly (pictures are good). :)

Comment: Its little hard to understand due to the way you posted this question but you can still follow what TrueBlueAussie said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example for targeting 3rd column is as below:

```
$('tr').find('td:eq(2)').click(function() {
    window.location = 'http://example.com';
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hkFdb/1)

Comment: i solved my issue and Thanx a lot Manoj Yadav for your suitable response...cheers..:)